# create a unlimited multilevel nested list from a recursive array

Tags: php, associative-array

Can anyone please assist me with the logic of looping through a recursive array and creating a multi level nested list using php. I have not been very successful in getting beyond the top level list nodes.

please see array below:

```
Dump => array(6) {
  [0] => array(5) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "1"
    ["label"] => string(13) "address types"
    ["slug"] => string(17) "admin/addresstype"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
    ["has_children"] => bool(false)
  }
  [1] => array(5) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "3"
    ["label"] => string(9) "dashboard"
    ["slug"] => string(15) "admin/dashboard"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
    ["has_children"] => bool(false)
  }
  [2] => array(6) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "5"
    ["label"] => string(16) "feature category"
    ["slug"] => string(21) "admin/featurecategory"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
    ["has_children"] => bool(true)
    ["children"] => array(2) {
      [0] => array(6) {
        ["id"] => string(1) "4"
        ["label"] => string(7) "feature"
        ["slug"] => string(13) "admin/feature"
        ["parent_id"] => string(1) "5"
        ["has_children"] => bool(true)
        ["children"] => array(2) {
          [0] => array(5) {
            ["id"] => string(1) "2"
            ["label"] => string(6) "status"
            ["slug"] => string(12) "admin/status"
            ["parent_id"] => string(1) "4"
            ["has_children"] => bool(false)
          }
          [1] => array(5) {
            ["id"] => string(1) "7"
            ["label"] => string(4) "menu"
            ["slug"] => string(10) "admin/menu"
            ["parent_id"] => string(1) "4"
            ["has_children"] => bool(false)
          }
        }
      }
      [1] => array(5) {
        ["id"] => string(1) "9"
        ["label"] => string(17) "subscription type"
        ["slug"] => string(22) "admin/subscriptiontype"
        ["parent_id"] => string(1) "5"
        ["has_children"] => bool(false)
      }
    }
  }
  [3] => array(5) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "6"
    ["label"] => string(8) "industry"
    ["slug"] => string(14) "admin/industry"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
    ["has_children"] => bool(false)
  }
  [4] => array(5) {
    ["id"] => string(1) "8"
    ["label"] => string(12) "subscription"
    ["slug"] => string(18) "admin/subscription"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
    ["has_children"] => bool(false)
  }
  [5] => array(5) {
    ["id"] => string(2) "10"
    ["label"] => string(4) "user"
    ["slug"] => string(10) "admin/user"
    ["parent_id"] => string(1) "0"
    ["has_children"] => bool(false)
  }
}
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: By "nested list" do you mean in `HTML`, as in `ul` or `ol`?

Comment: yes an HTML <ul>, cheers.

Comment: It would be better if you posted your attempts, then people could correct/add to it rather than having to do everything on their own. This seems like you haven't really made much effort at all.

Comment: You can review this comment for non-nested arrays. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23916237/build-recursive-nested-menu-from-array/53797708#53797708

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
/*
* Builds a tree based on parent child relationships
* @data: relationship data
* @parent: level to start at
*/
function buildTree(Array $data, $parent = 0) {
    $tree = array();
    foreach ($data as $d) {
        if ($d['ParentID'] == $parent) {
            $children = buildTree($data, $d['id']);
            // set a trivial key
            if (!empty($children)) {
                $d['_children'] = $children;
            }
            $tree[] = $d;
        }
    }
    return $tree;
}

function printTree(Array $data, $markup = ''){
    foreach($data as $elm){
        echo '<li data-id="'.$elm['TrainingID'].'">'.$elm['trainingName'].'<a href="#pages|admin|training?parent='.$elm['TrainingID'].'"><span class="addChild" title="Add a child training"></span></a><span class="editTraining" title="Edit"></span>';
        if(isset($elm['_children']))
        {
            echo '<ul>';
            printTree($elm['_children'], $markup);
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        print '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer , just one question though 
what is the significance of $markup?

Comment: May be I used that variable to store the generated html, ignore it's presence or even remove it.

Comment: printTree() produces invalid HTML, nesting a `<ul>` inside the parent `<ul>`. The child `<ul>` should be inside the parent `<li>`. I'll suggest an edit.