# Build recursive nested menu from array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, recursion

I'm trying to build a recursive menu which would look something like this when finished, with an infinite amount of nested items:

```
Homepage
Services
  Members
  Brokers
  Insurers
Products
```

My data is being linked together by a simple `parent_id` column in my table.

I have currently managed to grab all the pages in the table and add them into an array based on their `parent_id` (see below).

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0-0-1 0-1-2 0-2-12 0-3-27 0-4-28 0-5-29 0-6-30 0-7-31 0-8-33 
    [2] => 2-0-3 2-0-6 2-0-7 2-0-8 
    [3] => 3-0-4 3-0-5 
    [8] => 8-0-9 8-0-10 
    [12] => 12-0-13 12-0-20 
    [13] => 13-0-14 13-1-15 13-2-17 13-3-16 13-4-19 13-5-18 13-9-34 
    [20] => 20-0-21 20-1-22 20-2-24 20-3-23 20-4-26 20-5-25 20-6-11 
)
```

This is formatted as [`parent_id`] => `parent_id`-`sort_order`-`id` `parent_id`-`sort_order`-`id` and so on.

My code so far is as follows:

```
$sqlGetDropdownPages = "SELECT * FROM `cms_staticPages` ORDER BY `sortOrder` ASC";
$qryGetDropdownPages = mysql_query($sqlGetDropdownPages) or die(mysql_error());
$resGetDropdownPages = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryGetDropdownPages);
$totGetDropdownPages = mysql_num_rows($qryGetDropdownPages);

do {    

    $pageArray[$resGetDropdownPages['parent_id']] .= $resGetDropdownPages['parent_id'].'-'.$resGetDropdownPages['sortOrder'].'-'.$resGetDropdownPages['id'].' ';

} while($resGetDropdownPages = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryGetDropdownPages));

ksort($pageArray);

foreach($pageArray as $i => $value) {

    $explodePages = explode(' ',$value);

    foreach(array_filter($explodePages) as $i2 => $page) {

        $pageInfoExplode = explode('-',$page);

        $getPageInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cms_staticPages` WHERE `id` = '".$pageInfoExplode[2]."'"));

        echo $getPageInfo['identifier'].'<br />';

    }

}
```

Ran into a brick wall at this point and can't figure out what to do next.

I tried to explain this as well as I possibly can so if any clarification is needed just ask.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest that, instead of space-delimiting hyphen-delimited entries, to build a multi-dimensional array structure with string indices.  This may keep you from going insane (no promises, though).

Comment: You should seriously consider using a [nested set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). There's an excellent article on how to implement them with MySQL [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) (scroll past the adjacency list section). It might be a little trickier to wrap your head around but it's a far better way to store a tree in an RDBMS like MySQL

Comment: @Bojangles this does seem like a pretty good idea, but I would need this to work for a select menu. I am attempting something similar to WordPress pages whereby you can add new pages under a parent. Would this be relatively easy to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would index all the menu items (pages) by id first. In the second loop associate menu items with their parents and keep track of top level items.

One of the ways I would do it (Render method is just an example):

```
$sqlGetDropdownPages = "SELECT * FROM `cms_staticPages` ORDER BY `sortOrder` ASC";
$qryGetDropdownPages = mysql_query($sqlGetDropdownPages) or die(mysql_error());

//indexing pages by id
while ($pageRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($qryGetDropdownPages)) {
    $menuItems[$pageRow['id']] = new MenuItem($pageRow);
}

//associating pages with parents
foreach ($menuItems as $menuItem) {
    if ($menuItem->hasParent()) {
        $menuItem->addToParent($menuItems);
    } else {
        $topLevel[] = $menuItem;
    }
}

//$topLevel is an array of menuItems without parents
$render = '<ul>';
foreach ($topLevel as $menuItem) {
    $render .= $menuItem->render(true);
}
$render .= '</ul>';
```

MenuItem class would look something like this

```
class MenuItem {

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $data;

    /**
     * @var MenuItem[]
     */
    private $children = array();

    /**
     * @var MenuItem
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Finds the parent in the collection and adds itself to it
     * @param MenuItem[] $menuItems
     */
    public function addToParent($menuItems) {
        if (isset($menuItems[$this->data['parent_id']])) {
            $this->parent = $menuItems[$this->data['parent_id']];
            $this->parent->addChild($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasParent() {
        return empty($this->data['parent_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @param MenuItem $child
     */
    public function addChild(MenuItem $child) {
        $this->children[] = $child;
    }

    /**
     * Renders the menu with ul li
     * @param bool $withChildren
     * @return string
     */
    public function render($withChildren = false) {
        $render = '<li>' . $this->data['identifier'] . '</li>';

        if ($withChildren) {
            $render .= '<ul>';
            foreach ($this->children as $child) {
                $render .= $child->render(true);
            }
            $render .= '</ul>';
        }

        return $render;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I roughly understand how this works (I've never delved this far into PHP before). However, when I echo $render all I get is: <ul></ul>

Comment: what's in the $topLevel array? Do the var_dump($topLevel) after the second loop.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply :) It's NULL

Comment: How about $menuItems?

Comment: How do you store the pages with no parent? Is the parent_id null in the db for those records?

Comment: Ah that could be why, if the page is a top level page then the parent_id is 0.

Comment: Ok, try replacing the isset with empty in the hasParent method. I modified the code too.

Comment: empty didn't seem to want to play ball so I added an if statement which has solved it! if($this->data['parent_id'] != 0) { return $this->data['parent_id']; } Thanks very much for your awesome solution :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54661/discussion-between-scott-bowers-and-namesnik).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that after extracting all menu items from the database, it outputs an output as follows.

```
$items = [
[
    'id' => '1',
    'parent_id' => '0',
    'title' => 'Menu 1',
],
[
    'id' => '2',
    'parent_id' => '0',
    'title' => 'Menu 2',
],
[
    'id' => '3',
    'parent_id' => '2',
    'title' => 'Menu 2 1',
],
[
    'id' => '4',
    'parent_id' => '0',
    'title' => 'Menu 3',
],
[
    'id' => '5',
    'parent_id' => '4',
    'title' => 'Menu 3 1',
],
[
    'id' => '6',
    'parent_id' => '5',
    'title' => 'Menu 3 1 1',
],
[
    'id' => '7',
    'parent_id' => '5',
    'title' => 'Menu 3 1 2',
],
[
    'id' => '8',
    'parent_id' => '7',
    'title' => 'Menu 3 1 2 1',
],
[
    'id' => '9',
    'parent_id' => '4',
    'title' => 'Menu 3 2',
],
[
    'id' => '10',
    'parent_id' => '0',
    'title' => 'Menu 4',
]];
```

Let's write a function to process the data in Array format and return html

```
/**
 * Recursive and prints the elements of the given parent id.
 * @param $items
 * @param string $parentId
 */
function buildNestedItems($items, $parentId = "0", $wrapperTag = 'ul', $itemTag = 'li')
{
    // Parent items control
    $isParentItem = false;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item['parent_id'] === $parentId) {
            $isParentItem = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Prepare items
    $html = "";
    if ($isParentItem) {
        $html .= "<$wrapperTag>";
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item['parent_id'] === $parentId) {
                $html .= "<$itemTag>" . $item['title'] . "</$itemTag>";
                $html .= buildNestedItems($items, $item['id']);
            }
        }
        $html .= "</$wrapperTag>";
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Let's print the prepared html i page

```
<div class="menu">
    <?php echo buildNestedItems($items); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my example code to build nested menu for Zurb Foundation, using recursive function in PHP. Very simple and clean.

```
// call the function
build_menu();

//----------------------------

// recursive function
function build_menu($parent = "", $tab=""){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cat WHERE parent='$parent' ORDER BY category ASC";
    $q = mysql_query($sql);
    if (mysql_num_rows($q)) {
        if (empty($parent)):
            print $tab."<ul>\n";
        else:
            print $tab."<ul class='dropdown'>\n";
        endif;
        while($d = mysql_fetch_object($q)) {
            $has_child = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from cat where parent='$d->code'") );
            $tag = ($has_child ? " class='has-dropdown'" : "");
            $nl  = ($has_child ? "\n" : "");

            print $tab."\t"."<li".$tag."><a href='cat.php?cat=$d->code'>$d->category</a>$nl";

            if ($has_child) build_menu($d->code, $tab."\t");

            print $tab."</li>\n";
        }
        print $tab."</ul>\n";
    }
}
```